# Python minidom XML parser - ignore child tags

Tags: python, xml-parsing, minidom

I have a XML file which looks like:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        I am too good <italic>to be true</italic>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Now, When I want to extract the data within the "tag2" tags,
then assuming the XML file is read into the "XML_data" variable:

```
XML_data.getElementsByTagName('tag1')[0].getElementsByTagName('tag2')[0].childNodes[0].data
evaluates to "I am too good"
and 
XML_data.getElementsByTagName('tag1')[0].getElementsByTagName('tag2')[0].getElementsByTagName('italic')[0].childNodes[0].data
evaluates to "to be true"
```

What I want is to be able to extract the whole chunk within tag2, by ignoring the italic tags. i.e, I want my out put to be

```
"I am too good <italic>to be true</italic>"
```

How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: You can't - as your code suggests, the `<italic>` text is a separate node. You will have to decide which nodes should count as "in-line" and deal with them separately.

Comment: How tied are you to the minidom library? The DOM API is *very* cumbersome and verbose; you may want to use the ElementTree API (also part of the Python stdlib); it would make this task *far, far simpler*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see. I will give the ElementTree API a try. Just to expedite my understanding, how would one do it with the ElementTree API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally used  ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

def extractTextFromElement(elementName, stringofxml):
    tree = ET.fromstring(stringofxml)
    for child in tree.getiterator():
        if child.tag == elementName:
            len = ET.tostring(child)
            return re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', len)


usage: extractTextFromElement('tag2', XML_data)
```